# How to overcome BeanLocator is null error in Liferay while running a Scheduler?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I am developing a Liferay portlet using Eclipse IDE. I just created an entity called "USerDetails" in service.xml. Table "USerDetails" is created in the DB and I could save UserDetails entity to the DB.

Now, what I want is, I want to run a Scheduler to update the DB, I am using Quartz scheduler for that. Consider that, I need to update the "Age" column of UserDetails using Quartz scheduler.

My scheduler is running properly, but, table updation is not happening; its throwing

```
Sep 06, 2013 5:35:17 PM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl error
SEVERE: BeanLocator is null for servlet context User-Details-portlet
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I tried by adding service jar in the build path, still its throwing the same. Please help me to sole this.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand where your scheduler is running... in your portlet or in a separate application?

Comment: I hope you are following the approach in [this article](http://itsliferay.blogspot.in/2012/08/implement-scheduler-in-liferay-61.html) to create scheduler in liferay. If not then it would be helpful to know how you are doing it in liferay. Thanks

Comment: check if this is the issue with you http://www.solutionanalysts.com/blog/classnotfoundexception-springfactoryutil-maven-based-build and check your console properly for actual error log. For BeanLocator null, there can be many reason, primarily it wont able to find the bean you are trying to access

Comment: Thanks for all. My scheduler is in portlet only. I just started it by overriding init() method. Now its working perfectly. Is there any issue, if I am starting from init()?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Bean Locator null, not set problem by running my IDE(Eclipse Luna) as `Administrator`, and it worked.Hope it is useful for you too, good luck!